# Using GNURadio in Python

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, gnuradio

I am trying to use GNURadio on Python 3.7. I am running on Windows 10 and using Anaconda.

Every time I try to import GNURadio, I get the following

---

```
import gnuradio

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-9dfe3f3e2626>", line 1, in <module>
    import gnuradio

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gnuradio'
```

---

How can I import GNURadio in Python?

Answer (score 1):

GNU Radio 3.7 is not compatible with Python3; end of story. Also, it's GNU Radio's "legacy/maintenance support release series"; don't use if for anything new! (update:) As of spring 2022, GNU Radio 3.7 **is end-of-life** and should not be used in anything but legacy systems.

GNU Radio 3.8 is compatible with both Py3 and Py2, but the popular GCN development GNU Radio Windows installer  is built against Py2, so no, won't work for you either. 3.10 is available, and will be around for quite a while to enjoy. It is easily installable using your current Linux distro's package manager, or anaconda (on Linux, Mac OS X and Windows).

Installation instructions can be [found in the GNU Radio wiki](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=InstallingGR).